# Traceroute and mtr command are not working

Tags: traceroute

```
grace@DESKTOP-PTDHEDF:~$ sudo traceroute -m3 8.8.8.8
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 3 hops max
  1   *  *  *
  2   *  *  *
  3   *  *  *
```

Tried the following steps but the result still the same.

```
sudo apt-get install inetutils-traceroute
sudo apt install traceroute
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

```
grace@DESKTOP-PTDHEDF:~$ sudo mtr 8.8.8.8
mtr-packet: Failure to open IPv4 sockets: Permission denied
mtr-packet: Failure to open IPv6 sockets: Permission denied
mtr: Failure to start mtr-packet: Invalid argument
```

mtr command is also not working

Any idea that what I still need to do?

Thank you.

Comment: It is working, you just don't have permission to run it in your account.

Comment: Try running the command with `sudo`?

Comment: Since `traceroute` and `mtr` do raw packet manipulation,  you must run them as a privileged user, e.g. `sudo mtr 8.8.8.8`. Read `man sudo sudoers traceroute mtr`.

Comment: Thank you. I try to run the command with sudo, but its still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and fixed by running wsl as administrator in Windows :)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  Microsoft strongly recommends that you don't run WSL as Administrator in Windows as it can create serious security and stability issues with Windows.  That should be a *clue* to why networking isn't working for you in WSL, but not a long-term solution.